# regex exclude space from \W

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What I have now: `preg_match("[\W|_]",$string)`, which matches any non-word character and underscores. However, I only want to match strings containing `\w` and individual spaces in the middle of the string (as opposed to `$string` starting or ending with any number of spaces), but not underscores. Thanks for your help!

Examples that should be matched: `Example 123` or `One Two Three`.
Examples that should be rejected: `example&` or (starting with one ore more spaces, and multiple spaces between "Example" and "of) `Example  of foo`.

Comment: Use a negative lookahead.

Comment: So you want to have it not allow spaces in the middle of the string?  So can contain any number of spaces buffering the front and back, but inside the string you want only non-word chars (minus space), and underscore allowed?

Comment: @Mooseman Could you also perhaps provide some sample inputs and expected lines to be matched or rejected?

Comment: I think your syntax above is incorrect. If you want to alternate with OR than you should use (\W|_). Also your regex needs delimiters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, so you don't need to catch the results of the match - just to test whether or not the string matches some pattern. That can be done with...

```
$pattern = '/^[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9 ]*[A-Z0-9])?$/i';
```

... but that's destined to fail if you want to cover letters outside of ASCII range. You should use this instead then:

```
$pattern = '/^[\p{L}0-9](?:[\p{L}0-9 ]*[\p{L}0-9])?$/u';
```

Check the [demo](http://ideone.com/BRAgV3) to see that in action.

Comment: This is matching `$string` when it ends with spaces. What needs to be changed? Thanks!